# Map values between two arrays to generate a flat, associative array

Tags: php, arrays, mapping, associative-array

I have two arrays, one is a list of status IDs and the corresponding numbers of records that are that status ID. The second array is the names of the statuses. I'd like to tie them together so I have one array I can use in a graph.

The first array is

```
[
    ["status" => NULL, "number" => "2355"],
    ["status" => "1", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "2", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "3", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "4", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "7", "number" => "1"]
]
```

and the second is

```
[
    "Undelivered",
    "Sent",
    "Bounced",
    "Delivered",
    "Opened",
    "Clicked",
    "Logged In",
    "Completed",
    "Committed"
]
```

I have this code

```
$data = $this->_get_email_status();
$statii = $this->model->option_status;
foreach($statii as $index => $status) {
    $data[$index][TC_STATUS] = $status;
}
```

Which almost does what I want, except each array key has an array in it, which isn't quite what I need. This is what I am getting

```
[
    ["status" => "Undelivered", "number" => "2355"],
    ["status" => "Sent", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "Bounced", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "Delivered", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "Opened", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "Clicked", "number" => "1"],
    ["status" => "Logged In"],
    ["status" => "Completed"],
    ["status" => "Committed"]
]
```

And this is what I wanted:

```
[
    "Undelivered" => "2355",
    "Sent" => "1",
    "Bounced" => "1",
    "Delivered" => "1",
    "Opened" => "1",
    "Completed" => "1"
]
```

I'm sure there must be a way to do this programmatically but I seem to be going around in circles!

Comment: You don't want to _add_ anything below the `status` key, as you are currently doing - you want to _remove_ the `status` key, and _instead_ use your status _name_ as the _new_ key, and the value from the `number` element, as the new value.

Comment: `$data[$index][$status] = $data[$index]['number']; unset($data[$index]['status']); unset($data[$index]['number']);` as the body of your foreach loop should do it, I suppose. (Not tested, because I don't want to have to re-type your data as actual PHP code. Next time you ask such a question, please present the data in form of a `var_export`, or encoded as JSON - that's something we can _directly_ work with.)

Comment: yes, thank you, apologies i used our debug::dump which isn't quite the same as var_export..

Comment: sometimes typing it out into stackoverflow unmixes the mind :)

Comment: @user14989191 Please review my substantial edit of your question and make sure that my changes accurately reflect your intentions and expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to @CBroe , I made a new array and got the output as I wanted...

```
 $data = $this->_get_email_status();
            $statii = $this->model->option_status;
            $s = array();
            foreach($statii as $index => $status) {
                $s[$status] = $data[$index]['number'];
            }
```

Comment: hint, you may want to start using short syntax `[]` instead of `array()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the first array and map the numeric/null values to the corresponding value in the second array.

It is a little string that you have a `null` value in the payload, but simply cast that `null` to an integer and it will become `0` as desired.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X6uA9))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as ['status' => $i, 'number' => $n]) {
    $result[$array2[(int) $i]] = $n;
}
var_export($result);
```